# Insert row below a specific text (text occurrence times) and move parts of it below vba-excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert a row below every "item:". If there are n "item" in a cell, I want to add n rows below that row and put in the text after every "item" and ":end". How can I do that?

```
e.g.:
Col A
Move item:apple:end, item:banana:end, item:ball:end
Move item:boy:end, item:straw:end

and the result like this:
Col A:
Move item::end,item::end,item::end
apple
banana
ball
Move item::end, item::end
boy
straw

Can anyone help me? Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
Sub expandInsert()
    Dim re As New RegExp    ' need to check regex in Tools - References (VBE menu)
    
    With re
        .Pattern = "item\:([^\:]+)\:end"
        .Global = True
    End With
    
    Set cl = Sheets(1).Range("A1")  ' set start sell
    
    Do
        txt = cl.Text
        If txt = vbNullString Then Exit Do
    
        Set res = re.Execute(txt)
        
        If res.Count > 0 Then
            cl.Value = re.Replace(txt, "item::end")  ' removes submatches from string in the cell
            cl.Offset(1).Resize(res.Count).EntireRow.Insert
            For Each s1 In res
                For Each s2 In s1.SubMatches ' matches inside () of .Pattern
                    Set cl = cl.Offset(1)
                    cl.Value = s2
                Next
            Next
        End If
        
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1)   ' process next string
    Loop
End Sub
```

> Before:

[image]

> After:

[image]

Comment: can you explain this line to me?

.Pattern = "item\:([^\:]+)\:end"

Comment: This defines the search pattern: the fragment must always start with `item:` and end with `:end`, and the captured fragment between them `([^\:]+)` can contain 1+ any characters except `:`. See e.g. https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre

Comment: The \ characters, which escape special characters, do not interfere, but are probably unnecessary in this situation. You can leave the pattern as `item:([^:]+):end`

Answer (score 0):

Read up on Find and Offset, might work?

/Staffan